# SensorEventListener

Tags: android, события

Реализую я интерфейс `SensorEventListener` в `MainActivity` и собственно его методы:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

}
@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
```

В `OnCreate` добавил

```
mSensorMgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor accelerometer = mSensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    if (accelerometer != null) {
        mSensorMgr.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
```

При "встряхивании" телефона появляется всплывающее сообщение, хотя оно нигде не было указано...откуда оно вызывается и как его убрать?

[image: Toast]

Comment: Есть вероятность что у вас есть параллельный процесс, но мне кажется что просто ошибка в коде. В таких целях хорош LayotInspector отличный инструмент, чтоб выдрать I'd и задать поиск по проекту, сразу поймёте откуда и как.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что `onSensorChanged` работает в фоновом потоке и для того чтобы работать в `UI` необходимо выделить на это поток:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        App.showToast("SHAKE");
                    }
                });
```